# $\forall y\in\overline{xz}, f(x)>f(y)$. Then $\exists$ a ball center at $x$ such that $\forall x'\in B$, $f(x')>f(y')$ for any $y'\in\overline{x'z}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

$x,y,z$ are points in $\mathbb R^2$. $\overline{xz}$ denotes the segment connecting $x,z$.

$f(x)>f(y)$ for any $y\in\overline{xz}$.

> Q1. $f$ is continuous. Then, there exists a ball center at $x$ such that for any $x'\in B$, $f(x')>f(y')$ for any $y'\in\overline{x'z}$

My guess is that because $f$ is lower-semi-continuous, for any $a,b$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$, we have a ball $B(a)$ such that $\forall a'\in B(a)$, $f(a')>f(b)$.

Step 2: Also because $f$ is upper semi continuous, for any $a,b$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$, we have a ball $B(b)$ such that $\forall b'\in B(b)$, $f(a)>f(b')$.

Step 3: Therefore, because $f$ is continuous, for any $a,b$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$, we have balls $B(a)$ and $B(b)$ such that, for any $a'\in B(a)$ and $b'\in B(b)$, $f(a')>f(b')$.

I am not sure how to rigorously going from step 2 to step 3. But it seems like that if the step 3 is correct then our problem is solved.

> Q2. $f$ is lower semi-continuous. Can we still claim that there exists a ball center at $x$ such that for any $x'\in B$, $f(x')>f(y')$ for any $y'\in\overline{x'z}$

For Q2, I guess that the claim is wrong because we cannot repeat the second step in the previous proof. Do you think I am correct?